Is there a way to share plain text to another app without the user having to choose that other app
I am trying to allow my app to share some plain text to another app called 'macrodroid'. As the destination app is always the same I don't want my users to have to manually select the app every single time so I want to know if it is possible to send the text without the user having to choose. I couldn't find a solution for this myself and when searching online they all seem to require user input.
This is what I have so far, but as I said this forces the user to choose an app
val sintent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
sintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "variable to share text to macrodroid here")
sintent.setType("text/plain")
startActivity(sintent)


use the below function.
fun shareTextToApp(context: Context, text: String, packageName: String) {
    // Create the intent
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intent.type = "text/plain"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)

    // Set the target app's package name
    intent.setPackage(packageName)

    // Verify that the app is installed and can handle the intent
    if (intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
        context.startActivity(intent)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "App not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}


I can't believe I missed the setPackage function, thank you so much!
